# R: adding a dummy variable column to xts timeseries object

Tags: r, time-series, xts, dummy-variable

I have a xts time series object made up of minute by minute intraday trading data for 2015. I would like to add a dummy variable denoting 1 as an event day or 0 as a nonevent day.

Since the dummy variable is not inherently a time series, is it possible for me to add this to my trading data?

How should I construct the dummy column?

How can it be added to the existing xts?

New to R, so please be as specific as possible in your answer. Thank you!

Comment: If you want people to be as specific as possible in their answer, it would help if you would be as specific as possible in your question (i.e. provide a [minimal reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/271616) showing the input and expected output).

Answer (score 3):

`xts` is based on `zoo`, and the zoo FAQ (question 4) has this line about differing data types:

> A "zoo" object may be (1) a numeric vector, (2) a numeric matrix or 
>   (3) a factor but may not contain both a numeric vector and factor.

So as long as your 0s and 1s are `numeric`, not `factor`, you should be ok. It's not a hugely efficient storage medium, but storage efficiency might not be your bottleneck.

An example:

```
timestamp <- seq.POSIXt(from=as.POSIXct("2016-10-12 09:00"), 
                    to=as.POSIXct("2016-10-13 09:00"), 
                    by="min")
dat <- rnorm(length(timestamp))
foo <- xts(dat,order.by=timestamp)
```

Now that indicator variable:

```
#make this example reproducible:
set.seed(123)

dummy2 <- sample(c("event","non-event"), size=length(timestamp),
    replace=TRUE)
foo2 <- xts(dummy2, order.by=timestamp)
merged <- cbind(foo, foo2)
```

And that warns you:

```
In merge.xts(..., all = all, fill = fill, suffixes = suffixes) :
  NAs introduced by coercion
```

Indeed:

```
summary(merged)
     Index                          ..1                ..2      
 Min.   :2016-10-12 09:00:00   Min.   :-3.38110   Min.   : NA   
 1st Qu.:2016-10-12 15:00:00   1st Qu.:-0.64010   1st Qu.: NA   
 Median :2016-10-12 21:00:00   Median : 0.04047   Median : NA   
 Mean   :2016-10-12 21:00:00   Mean   : 0.03025   Mean   :NaN   
 3rd Qu.:2016-10-13 03:00:00   3rd Qu.: 0.67461   3rd Qu.: NA   
 Max.   :2016-10-13 09:00:00   Max.   : 3.25034   Max.   : NA   
                                                  NA's   :1441
```

But if it's a numeric:

```
dummy3 <- sample(0:1, size=length(timestamp), replace=TRUE)
foo3 <- xts(dummy3, order.by=timestamp)
merged <- cbind(foo, foo3)
```

returns silently (and no news is good news). Let's have a look:

```
summary(merged)

         Index                          ..1                ..2        
 Min.   :2016-10-12 09:00:00   Min.   :-3.38110   Min.   :0.0000  
 1st Qu.:2016-10-12 15:00:00   1st Qu.:-0.64010   1st Qu.:0.0000  
 Median :2016-10-12 21:00:00   Median : 0.04047   Median :0.0000  
 Mean   :2016-10-12 21:00:00   Mean   : 0.03025   Mean   :0.4983  
 3rd Qu.:2016-10-13 03:00:00   3rd Qu.: 0.67461   3rd Qu.:1.0000  
 Max.   :2016-10-13 09:00:00   Max.   : 3.25034   Max.   :1.0000
```

Since column 2 is numeric, we don't compare using equality; if that isn't intuitive to you, check out Circle One of the [R Inferno](http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf) (caution: PDF).

```
summary(merged[merged[,2] > 0.5 ,1] )
summary(merged[merged[,2] < 0.5 ,1] )
```

There's probably a more elegant way of doing that, but it'll get you started.

If you plan on working with `xts` more than trivially, I recommend the advice from the authors of `xts`:

> At the core of an xts object is a zoo object from the package of the same
>   name. ... Most of the details surrounding zoo objects apply equally to
>   xts. As it would be redundant to simply retell the excellent introductory zoo
>   vignette, the reader is advised to read, absorb, and re-read that documentation
>   to best understand the power of this class.